# Registration Form: Unable to Hide Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, view

In creating a new application I have used  marklocklear example (https://github.com/marklocklear/devise_multi_tentant) for assistance in creating a multi-tenant environment.  It works well.

The next thing I wanted to do I thought would be simple but has turned into quite the niggle for me.

All I wanted to do is rather than having the initial admin user have to enter an organization name (which is not necessary in my application), I wanted to hide that field.

Sign Up Form (that works):

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<% resource.organization ||= Organization.new %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>
    <%= f.fields_for :organization do |org| %>
      <div><%= 'Organization or Company Name' %><br />
      <%= org.text_field :name %></div>
    <% end %>
  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>
  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

So, I did this to try to hide the field:

```
<%= f.fields_for :organization do |org| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

But I get an error.

The baffling thing to me is that if I leave the field in, but do not enter a value everything still works properly -- this is unexpected.  Since (as part of my troubleshooting) I removed the field completely -- and got an error message stating the form could not be processed because the organization part was blank.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: use `org.hidden_field` not `f.hidden_field`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max:  Thank you.  As you know, that worked like a charm.  The field is now hidden and the form submits properly.  Thanks.

```
<%= f.fields_for :organization do |org| %>
      <%= org.hidden_field :name %>
<% end %>
```